# .OrderBy() Não ordena de forma correta - Aspnet Core

Tags: asp.net-core, order-by

Em uma aplicação Aspnet Core 2.2, eu tinha o seguinte código que selecionava o campo de uma tabela e instruia a ordenar pelo Texto:

**Controller**:

```
            //Bairros
            ViewBag.Bairros = _context.Imoveis.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
            { Text = c.Bairro, Value = c.Bairro }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).Distinct();
```

**View**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="bairro" asp-items="@ViewBag.Bairros" class="form-control">
         <option value="0">Todos os bairros</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Nessa versão anterior o código funcionava. Ao passar para a versão 3.1, o código não funciona, ele fica da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ref as versões,

Anterior: EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.8, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql 2.1.0
Atual: EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.10, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql 3.2.4

Será que a atualização de versão tem efeito sobre a querie?

Comment: Na boa, é por isso que a comunidade está como está. Tenho feito as perguntas na EO em inglês e a galera ajuda de boa. Os "Sabichões moderadores" daqui alem de não ajudar, negativam a pergunta. Eu não perguntei a esmo, coloquei o maximo de informação possivel. Sei que não é todos, mas desculpa. tem que afundar mesmo.

Comment: Inverteu de tal forma que nem sei por onde começar. Primeiro que voto é secreto, acho estranho afirmar quem foi ou deixou de ser. Segundo que se tem algo a questionar, seria mais apropriado no [meta]. Terceiro que é irrelevante se perguntou a esmo ou não, pois motivação de postar não é critério para voto, conteúdo sim. Quarto, sobre ter colocado o máximo de informação possível, está longe disso. Precisa aprender fazer um [mcve] nas próximas (o link ensina). Sobre o "tem que afundar", vai do compromisso dos usuários. Só não afunda mais pq felizmente temos moderadores e usuários que votam certo.

Comment: PS: hoje que eu li o post tb negativei, mas por mera indexação do conteúdo, nada pessoal (você fez o [Tour] né? lá explica). Fechei a pergunta provisoriamente para evitar "o site afundar", mas se leu a documentação (que não é invenção minha), com certeza vai achar correto, pois já aprendeu que para termos um site melhor, basta [edit] e melhorar o post, que ele é automaticamente revisado **pela comunidade toda**, não só pela moderação. E é democrático, via voto. Ou seja, se o moderador errou, com certeza outros vão reabrir e positivar. Se não ocorrer, bom, aí o problema é mesmo na pergunta...

Comment: @Bacco Eu na época fiz esse comentário infeliz devido a uma frustração, e aqui peço desculpas a comunidade. Hj eu vejo que a comunidade precisa de ajuda de pessoal experiente. Ser programador envolve muitas facetas, e existem N formas de começar a programar. Li sim quase todas as info do Meta, de como fazer as perguntas claras e objetivas e hoje eu evito de fazer perguntas, mas tento ajudar de acordo com o nível que possuo e inclusive incentivando o pessoal negativado a ler o Meta para fazer perguntas melhores, uma vez que estamos aqui para ajudar e não fazer code para outros mas vlw o toque

Comment: Fico feliz de vc ter revisado alguns pontos. Ultimamente qdo faço contraponto, imagino que vai vir "pedrada" de volta (tanto que escrevi reticente de se devia ou não). Espero que veja os moderadores como pessoas normais que estão tentando cumprir um objetivo (e que tambem às vezes se manifestam quando se sentem injustiçados, como eu fiz aqui), mas que o objetivo final é sempre produzir resultados positivos. Obrigado pelo retorno cordial, anda raro de ver isso por aqui. E considere sempre votos e fechamentos como mera organização, e não "like" ou "dislike".

Comment: Eu que agradeço, no fim estamos todos aqui aprendendo. E vamos em frente ✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de pesquisar fiz algumas mudanças e o OrderBy() funcionou.

O Código anterior:

```
    ViewBag.Bairros = _context.Imoveis.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
    { Text = c.Bairro, Value = c.Bairro }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).Distinct();
```

O código refeito:

```
ViewBag.Bairros = _context.Imoveis.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
    { Text = c.Bairro, Value = c.Bairro }).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.Value);
```